# Sed command to replace to a line if a matching string is there and it is not commented

Tags: php, sed

I need to search for a file having a string and replace whole line with a new line only if it is not commented. Actual scenario is that I need to replace the include of a file with new file only if the include statement is not commented.

Example:

```php
include("../mytest.php");
// include("../mytest.php");
```

Expected result:

```php
require_once("mytestnew.php");
// include("../mytest.php");
```

I have tried some of the following sed commands found at different places on web:

```sh
sed -i '/^[\t]*\/\/.*/!/include.*mytest.php/c\require_once("mytestnew.php");' file.php
sed -i '/^[\t]*\/\/.*/!{include.*mytest.php/c\require_once("mytestnew.php");}' file.php
sed -i '/^[\t]*\/\/.*/b;include.*mytest.php/c\require_once("mytestnew.php");' file.php
sed -i '/^[\t]*\/\/.*/!s/include.*mytest.php/c\require_once("mytestnew.php");/g' file.php
```

In most of the other cases as well either I am getting unexpected { or s etc error or the result is not as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sed 's#^[ \t]*include("../mytest.php");#require_once("../mytestnew.php");#' inputfile
```

If you want to preserve the leading whitespace in the uncommented `include` lines, try:

```
sed 's#^\([ \t]*\)include("../mytest.php");#\1require_once("../mytestnew.php");#' inputfile
```

Comment: Nothing is getting replaced for me :( Is sed environment dependent.. I am new to it. I am having ubuntu and lamp environment

Comment: With some twists in your answer it worked for me..included some escape characters... Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just:

```
sed 's|^include("../mytest.php");|require_once("mytestnew.php");|g' file.php
```

Comment: I don't get it, I just tried on file only containing your example and it worked. Did you give the filename at the end of sed command?

Comment: What is the output of `which sed`?

Comment: I am not sure why it did not worked, i was having no change in this case and no error as well.. but posted what worked for me.. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I got it right after using escape character:

```
sed -i 's#^[\t]*include.*mytest.php");#require_once("\.\.\/mytestnew.php");#' file.php
```